Scala 3 generic method type parameter not working
Works:
trait Transformer[A, B] {
  def transform(a: A): B
}

class TransformerImpl extends Transformer[Int, String] {
  override def transform(value: Int): String = {
    value.toString
  }
}

This is what I want, because the trait having one parameter is simpler and because the concrete value of B is determined by A. However, it does not work.
trait Transformer2[A] {
  def transform[B](a: A): B
}

class Transformer2Impl extends Transformer2[Int] {
  override def transform[String](value: Int): String = {
    value.toString
  }
}

Error:
-- [E007] Type Mismatch Error: --------
3 |    value.toString
  |    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |    Found:    String
  |    Required: String

This too, with a different method signature, does not work:
class Transformer2IntToIntImpl extends Transformer2[Int] {
  override def transform(value: Int): Int = {
    value
  }
}

Error:
-- Error: ----------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |class Transformer2IntToIntImpl extends Transformer2[Int] {
  |      ^
  |class Transformer2IntToIntImpl needs to be abstract, since def transform[B](a: A): B in trait Transformer2 is not defined 
  |(Note that
  | parameter A in def transform[B](a: A): B in trait Transformer2 does not match
  | parameter Int in override def transform(value: Int): Int in class Transformer2IntToIntImpl
  | )
-- [E038] Declaration Error: ---------------------------------------------------
2 |  override def transform(value: Int): Int = {
  |               ^
  |method transform has a different signature than the overridden declaration
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

2 errors found

Based on the errors, I tried several alternatives, but with no success.

Generally, any function with signature f[A](...): A that has no A in the inputs must throw / diverge. In particular, def transform[Str](value: Int): Str must throw / diverge.

This worked for me:
trait Transformer2[A] {
  type B
  def transform(a: A): B
}

class Transformer2Impl extends Transformer2[Int] {
  type B = String
  override def transform(value: Int): String = {
    value.toString
  }
}

class Transformer2IntToIntImpl extends Transformer2[Int] {
  type B = Int
  override def transform(value: Int): Int = {
    value
  }
}

val ans1 = new Transformer2Impl().transform(5)
// val ans1: String = 5

val ans2 = new Transformer2IntToIntImpl().transform(5)
// val ans2: Int = 5

I would still like to know if the original code failed - albeit with  convoluted  error messages - because it is syntactically incorrect.

It's not syntactically incorrect, it's semantically incorrect

The definitions
// (1)
trait Transformer[A, B] {
  def transform(a: A): B
}

or
// (2)
trait Transformer2[A] {
  type B
  def transform(a: A): B
}

mean that an implementation (for fixed A, B) of Transformer knows how to transform this fixed A into this fixed B.
About (1) vs. (2) see
Scala: Abstract types vs generics (answer)
Abstract types versus type parameters
This definition
// (3)
trait Transformer2[A] {
  def transform[B](a: A): B
}

means something different. Namely, its implementation (for fixed A) knows how to transform this fixed A into arbitrary B.

because the concrete value of B is determined by A

This is (2), not (3).
Here
// (4)
class Transformer2Impl extends Transformer2[Int] {
  override def transform[String](value: Int): String = {
    value.toString
  }
}

String in [String] is not standard java.lang.String (aka scala.Predef.String). You do not specify B. Actually you define new type parameter denoted String and this new type shadows standard String. It doesn't matter how to denote a type parameter. So (4) is exactly the same as
// (5)
class Transformer2Impl extends Transformer2[Int] {
  override def transform[B](value: Int): B = {
    value.toString
  }
}

That's why compile error.
It's better to switch on scalacOptions += "-Xlint:type-parameter-shadow", then you'll receive a warning in such situation.
Here
// (6)
class Transformer2IntToIntImpl extends Transformer2[Int] {
  override def transform(value: Int): Int = {
    value
  }
}

you obviously changed the signature, that's why compile error.
